# Is there a limit for single family residence as far a how large the main panel can be?

Tags: electrical

I currently have a 40/40 box that is full. I have seen 40/60's and 40/80's but I don't like tandem breakers and the gutters are quite full. I have seen a 54 breaker panel that would seem to provide the extra slots and while the width is the same as the current box, it is taller, which would provide more gutter space. Is it OK to use something larger than a 40 slot breaker in a single family residential setting? I could go with a sub panel but I don't have a good place close enough to the current panel. Also, going with the sub panel would require adding junction boxes which I would prefer not to have to use. 2 electricians so far have been wary of replacing the whole panel, but the only reservation seems to be that it is more work.

Comment: Picture of the existing panel?

Comment: What NEC edition is your local Authority Having Jurisdiction on, and do you have any local amendments? There were changes made in 2008 to allow lighting panelboards (including loadcenters) to be larger than 42 spaces, but a few local AHJs haven't kept up with those and may not accept 54- or 60-space loadcenters as a result

Comment: Revealing my ignorance what does 40/40, 40/60, 40/80 mean? (I edited to change "weary" to wary.) Why would electricians be reluctant to undertake the proposed job because it is more work? Do you think they are concerned they might be afoul of regulations?

Comment: 40 circuits for a single would seem to be plenty.  It does depend on the size of house and what you have.  I would check if some circuits are under use, maybe just two lights on a circuit, when that circuit could take 10, or two or three circuits for one bedroom, when one usually is okay/more than plenty.  Electric heating would take more circuits and fill a panel up faster.

Comment: @JimStewart The first number is the number of "spaces" - a.k.a., full size breakers. The second is the number of "circuits" - a.k.a., half size or tandem or double-stuff breakers. There used to be a hard code limit of 42 total circuits, but that is not a factor any more. Eaton CH only has (when I last checked, if I read things correctly) 15A and 20A as half size breakers in pairs. Other brands have a lot more, some including either singles (so you can make your own grouping) or quads (so you can have two pairs of half size circuit breakers that span two full size breakers with the

Comment: inner pair and outer pair each then capable of common trip to be used as a traditional double breaker (240V). Varies a lot by brand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as large as you can find. 40 or 42 spaces (varies by brand) is typically the largest, with most now offering double that in "circuits" using tandems, which as you know are limited in utility due to GFCI/AFCI and other factors.

Anything larger is likely to be *expensive*. Volume production makes a huge difference in end-user pricing, so the popular sizes get much better pricing than the unusual sizes.

A subpanel does *not* necessarily require junction boxes. The ideal setup, if you can do it, may be a subpanel right next to the existing panel, with large conduit (less than 24" long to avoid derates) between the panels. That could be above or below (but maximum height 6'7" so that is not always an option) or to the left or right.

The other thing to consider is where the circuits are going. Much of the time, but not always, when it comes to adding more than a few circuits most of them are going to one place - e.g., finishing a basement or garage or turning part of a house into an accessory dwelling unit. In those cases, a subpanel near the new circuit locations really *does* make sense, and sometimes you can use that to free up a few existing circuits in the main panel as well.

Comment: The limit of 42 came from the 2005 NEC and earlier, which established the limit in 408.35. It went away with the 2008 NEC. If the panel was installed on the 2005 or earlier code cycle, it will almost certainly have only been certified for up to 42 circuits, so it would be against labeling to put any tandems in to exceed that number of circuits.

Comment: @KMJ Ostensibly true. However, I know I have seen some references previously to certain panels that used to have the 42 limit - e.g., 30 spaces but only 12 could have tandems even though there was nothing physically different about the other 18 spaces - where the same exact panel is now allowed to have tandems everywhere and that existing versions of the same panel are allowed as well. But it may vary by manufacturer.

Comment: It certainly does vary by manufacturer. I've seen the label limit before.